# Qt QGLWidget GLuint array memory alignment issue

Tags: qt4, texture-mapping, memory-alignment, qglwidget

I'm following the [NeHe OGL tutorials](http://nehe.gamedev.net/) in Qt using QGLWidget subclasses.  So far I haven't had any problems, and on the [6th tutorial](http://nehe.gamedev.net/tutorial/texture_mapping/12038/) on texture mapping where he introduces texturing a rotating box. I had everything working and then tried messing around to add my own textures to each side of the cube.  I used the QGLWidget::bindTexture() function to load my 256x256 bmp files stored through the Qt Resource system and saved the GLuint id in a private member array. In paintGL() I call glBindTexture() with GL_TEXTURE_2D and one of the GLuint array elements as arguments before calling glBegin(GL_QUADS) and glEnd() for each face of the square. It compiles fine, but the box either renders completely white (as if maybe it can't find the textures) or else I get crazy black and white artifacting during the rotation draws with random lines shooting all over the screen.

While messing around I managed to fix the problem by adding another private data member to the end of my class declaration, when things magically started working, and settled on moving my declaration of the GLuint textures array up higher in the class declaration which seems to work.  I'm pretty ignorant about memory alignment, and that seems like the most obvious cause of what's going on and I would love an explanation of what's going on here.

In case it matters, this is on Qt 4.6, compiled on GCC 4.4.0 and GNU Make 3.8.1 in MinGW 5.1.6 (ya I should upgrade).

The code:
glwidget.hpp, the offending declaration commented at the bottom

```
    #ifndef GLWIDGET_HPP
    #define GLWIDGET_HPP

    #include <QtOpenGL>

    class QTimer;

    class GLWidget : public QGLWidget
    {
    Q_OBJECT

    public:
        GLWidget( QWidget *parent = 0 );
        ~GLWidget();

    protected:
        void initializeGL();
        void paintGL();
        void resizeGL( int width, int height );

    private:
        void drawCube();
        void loadTextures();

        QTimer  *m_timer;
        GLuint  m_textures[6]; // doesn't cause rendering problems here
        GLfloat m_xrot, m_yrot, m_zrot;
    //  GLuint  m_textures[6]; // causes rendering problems if declared here
    };

    #endif
```

glwidget.cpp

```
    #include "glwidget.hpp"

    #include <QTimer>

    GLWidget::GLWidget( QWidget *parent )
        : QGLWidget( QGLFormat(QGL::SampleBuffers), parent )
    {
        m_timer = new QTimer( this );
        m_timer->setSingleShot( false );
        connect( m_timer, SIGNAL(timeout()), this, SLOT(updateGL()) );
        m_timer->start( 7 );

        setWindowTitle( "NeHe Lesson 6" );
    }

    GLWidget::~GLWidget()
    {
        glDeleteTextures( 6, m_textures );
    }

    void GLWidget::initializeGL()
    {
        glShadeModel( GL_SMOOTH );  // Enable smooth shading
        qglClearColor( Qt::black );
        glClearDepth( 1.0f );   // Depth buffer setup
        glEnable( GL_DEPTH_TEST );
        glEnable( GL_TEXTURE_2D );
        glDepthFunc( GL_LEQUAL );
        glHint( GL_PERSPECTIVE_CORRECTION_HINT, GL_NICEST );

        loadTextures();
    }

    void GLWidget::loadTextures()
    {
        glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MIN_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );
        glTexParameteri( GL_TEXTURE_2D, GL_TEXTURE_MAG_FILTER, GL_LINEAR );

        m_textures[0] = bindTexture( QPixmap(":/img/scifi.bmp") );
        m_textures[1] = bindTexture( QPixmap(":/img/scifi2.bmp") );
        m_textures[2] = bindTexture( QPixmap(":/img/scifi3.bmp") );
        m_textures[3] = bindTexture( QPixmap(":/img/scifi4.bmp") );
        m_textures[4] = bindTexture( QPixmap(":/img/scifi5.bmp") );
        m_textures[5] = bindTexture( QPixmap(":/img/scifi6.bmp") );
    }

    void GLWidget::drawCube()
    {
        // Front face
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textures[0] );
        glBegin( GL_QUADS );
            glNormal3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
            glTexCoord2f( 0.0f, 0.0f ); glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f ); // Bottom left
            glTexCoord2f( 1.0f, 0.0f ); glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f ); // Bottom right
            glTexCoord2f( 1.0f, 1.0f ); glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ); // Top right
            glTexCoord2f( 0.0f, 1.0f ); glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ); // Top left
        glEnd();

        // Back face
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textures[1] );
        glBegin( GL_QUADS );
            glNormal3f( 0.0f, 0.0f, -1.0f );
            glTexCoord2f( 1.0f, 0.0f ); glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f ); // Bottom right
            glTexCoord2f( 1.0f, 1.0f ); glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f ); // Top right
            glTexCoord2f( 0.0f, 1.0f ); glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f ); // Top left
            glTexCoord2f( 0.0f, 0.0f ); glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f ); // Bottom left
        glEnd();

        // Top Face
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textures[2] );
        glBegin( GL_QUADS );
            glNormal3f( 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
            glTexCoord2f( 0.0f, 1.0f ); glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f ); // Top left
            glTexCoord2f( 0.0f, 0.0f ); glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ); // Bottom left
            glTexCoord2f( 1.0f, 0.0f ); glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ); // Bottom right
            glTexCoord2f( 1.0f, 1.0f ); glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f ); // Top right
        glEnd();

        // Bottom Face
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textures[3] );
        glBegin( GL_QUADS );
            glNormal3f( 0.0f, -1.0f, 0.0f );
            glTexCoord2f( 1.0f, 1.0f ); glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f ); // Top right
            glTexCoord2f( 0.0f, 1.0f ); glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f ); // Top left
            glTexCoord2f( 0.0f, 0.0f ); glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f ); // Bottom left
            glTexCoord2f( 1.0f, 0.0f ); glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f ); // Bottom right
        glEnd();

        // Right face
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textures[4] );
        glBegin( GL_QUADS );
            glNormal3f( 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
            glTexCoord2f( 1.0f, 0.0f ); glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f ); // Bottom right
            glTexCoord2f( 1.0f, 1.0f ); glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f ); // Top right
            glTexCoord2f( 0.0f, 1.0f ); glVertex3f( 1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ); // Top left
            glTexCoord2f( 0.0f, 0.0f ); glVertex3f( 1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f ); // Bottom left
        glEnd();

        // Left Face
        glBindTexture( GL_TEXTURE_2D, m_textures[5] );
        glBegin( GL_QUADS );
            glNormal3f( -1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
            glTexCoord2f( 0.0f, 0.0f ); glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f,-1.0f ); // Bottom left
            glTexCoord2f( 1.0f, 0.0f ); glVertex3f(-1.0f,-1.0f, 1.0f ); // Bottom right
            glTexCoord2f( 1.0f, 1.0f ); glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f, 1.0f ); // Top right
            glTexCoord2f( 0.0f, 1.0f ); glVertex3f(-1.0f, 1.0f,-1.0f ); // Top left
        glEnd();
    }

    void GLWidget::paintGL()
    {
        glClear( GL_COLOR_BUFFER_BIT | GL_DEPTH_BUFFER_BIT );
        glLoadIdentity();
        glTranslatef( 0.0f, 0.0f, -5.0f );
        glRotatef( m_xrot, 1.0f, 0.0f, 0.0f );
        glRotatef( m_yrot, 0.0f, 1.0f, 0.0f );
        glRotatef( m_zrot, 0.0f, 0.0f, 1.0f );
        drawCube();

        m_xrot += 0.3f;
        m_yrot += 0.2f;
        m_zrot += 0.4f;
    }

    void GLWidget::resizeGL( int width, int height )
    {
        if( height == 0 )
            height = 1;

        glViewport( 0, 0, width, height );
        glMatrixMode( GL_PROJECTION );
        glLoadIdentity();
        gluPerspective( 45.0f, static_cast<GLfloat>(width)/height, 0.1f, 100.0f );
        glMatrixMode( GL_MODELVIEW );
        glLoadIdentity();
    }
```